# Issue sorting output of Bootstrap-Datepicker

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

I am using the following Datepicker:
https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker

I have the datepicker set up to allow multiple date selections. It is working fine in that aspect. I am utilizing the "dateChanged" event to trigger a sort of the textbox so that the dates are in order. The code I have works when I step through it. But for some reason the textbox reverts back to the unsorted date list when the event has finished firing.

Here is the code that I have so far:

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $('#RequestedDatesDIV').datepicker({
                    daysOfWeekHighlighted: "0,6",
                    multidate: true,
                    autoclose: true,
                    todayHighlight: true
                })

                //Listen for the change event on the input
                .change(dateChanged)
                .on('changeDate', dateChanged);

            });

                   function dateChanged(ev) {
                       var DateBox = document.getElementById("Selection1").value;
                       var SelectedDates = [];
                       SelectedDates = DateBox.split(",")
                       DateBox = SelectedDates.sort();
                       alert(DateBox);
                   }

               </script>  

<div class="input-group date" id="RequestedDatesDIV">
span class="input-group-addon bluebase" id="basic-addon130"></span>                                
<asp:TextBox id="Selection1" CssClass="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<span id="Selection1_addon" class="input-group-addon redbase" runat="server">
<i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue is caused by a bug in the current version of the date-picker.
The fix for this is to change the listening event from "changeDate" to "hide".
Note: This will only work if you leave "autoclose" enabled.

```
//Listen for the change event on the input
            .change(dateChanged)
            .on('hide', dateChanged);
```